# How can i convert my already exist array to a new specific array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here is my Array of canada post shipping rate:

```
Array(
[Priority] => Array
    (
        [num] => 388.98
        [str] => Can$ 388.98
    )

[Xpresspost] => Array
    (
        [num] => 294.98
        [str] => Can$ 294.98
    )

[Regular] => Array
    (
        [num] => 97.14
        [str] => Can$ 97.14
    ))
```

Now i want to subtract the value of num by it's half and want's to make a new array from above array like this :

```
Array(
[Priority] => Array
    (
        [num] => 194.49
        [str] => Can$ 194.49
    )

[Xpresspost] => Array
    (
        [num] => 147.49
        [str] => Can$ 147.49
    )

[Regular] => Array
    (
        [num] => 48.57
        [str] => Can$ 48.57
    ))
```

So how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to itterate through your array ($inputArray):

```
$outputArray = array();
foreach($inputArray as $key => $value){
    $sum = $value['num']/2;
    $outputArray[$key] = array(
        'num' => $sum,
        'str' => 'Can$ '.$sum,
    );
}
```

Your output will be in **$outputArray** variable.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a foreach over your array

```
foreach($my_array  as $key => $value){
    $val = $value['num']/2;
    $value['num'] = $val;
    $value['str'] = 'Can$ ' .$val;
  }
```